# Git Clone Error message "permanently added to list of known hosts"

Tags: git, clone

when using git clone I accidentally entered in the ssh instead of the HTTP and got Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,(RSA) to the list of known hosts.

How do I go about remove this from my known host?

Comment: By editing `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. But note that it’s not an _error_ message, and in the end probably a good thing.

Comment: Also (besides the "not an error" thing), note that it's ssh, not git, that printed the message. Git runs other commands for you!

Answer (score 1):

You should run:

```
ssh-keygen -R github.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit `~/.ssh/known_hosts` and remove the line(s) you want.
Probably the last one(s).